# Anagram Bubble Sorter

Tags: code-golf, sorting

**The Challenge**

A bubble sort takes a list of non-repeating integers and sorts them in ascending order, with only the use of one operation: switching two numbers which are next to eachother.

However for this puzzle, you must take in two strings, which are both anagrams, and bubble sort the letters of the first string into the second.

**Example:**

Trap, Part

TRAP
TRPA
TPRA
PTRA
PTAR
PATR
PART

**Rules**

- Your program must only use the switching operation
- Your program must use the most optimal way of bubble sorting
- This is code golf, lowest amount of bytes wins!

Comment: Could you provide examples?

Comment: do we have to print each step?

Comment: @maltysen no, as long as you follow the rules provided its ok.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the sort algorithm used? In most bubble sorts I've seen, the example's T would quickly bubble down and the P would take longer to get in position. Here it seems to be the opposite.

Comment: @geobits The code does not have to be a specific algorithm. I listed that example because it follows the two rules: it only moves by switching and is the least possible moves for it

Comment: Your example shows some mixed case words on the first line and uppercase words on the second line. 1. Is the first line the input and the second line the desired output? 2. Should input and output be exactly like this, i.e., input separated by a comma, output separated by spaces? 3. Do we have to convert the input to uppercase?

Comment: @Dennis The program should not be case sensitive, i.e. PArt and TrAp should work with the program. And again, no output is required, and any input form is ok.

Comment: No output is required? Then I could just submit an empty program...

Comment: @Reto Koradi that makes no sense, you are not following the rules with that submission.You arent taking in two strings, and you arent modifying the first one with the switch movement to be equal to the second one.

Comment: If I understand your intentions, you want us to modify an array of letters in place using only swaps, using the minimum amount of swaps. I'm not sure how much sense this makes since a) Strings are immutable in many languages, so they can't be modified at all. b) That not at all what bubble sort does. Bubble sort is not about finding a minimum number of swaps, but about iterating over a list and conditionally swapping two adjacent elements if they're out of order.